# What's the right word for describing a short quote from an opera libretto?

Tags: word-choice

What's the right word for describing a short quote from an opera libretto?

> "I quoted this **fragment** from "The Magic Flute" opera just now
>   because..."?

or

> "I quoted this **passage** from "The Magic Flute" opera just now
>   because..."?

or

> "I quoted this **portion** from "The Magic Flute" opera just now
>   because..."?

or

> "I quoted this **stretch** from "The Magic Flute" opera just now
>   because..."?

or what?

Comment: You are quoting an excerpt *from the opera's libretto*.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - Do you mean that saying just "from opera." would be incorrect?

Comment: I'm saying that it would be CLEARER if you said "from the opera's *libretto*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small section of *music* from a larger work is generally called an "excerpt".

Example:

> That was *an excerpt from* Mozart's "The Magic Flute".

If you were quoting only the *lyrics* from a song or an opera then I would say stick to the word "*quote*".

> I quoted from Mozart's opera "The Magic Flute" just now because...

The reason I suggest this is because we say "an excerpt *from*", not "an excerpt of", so it would not flow very well if you "quoted *from* an excerpt *from*", if you see what I mean.

If you really wanted to specify a particular part of the opera then I believe most classical works are broken down into named or numbered *movements*.

Comment: Can I say "I quoted this excerpt from Mozart's opera..."? BTW, I am talking about quoting only the lyrics of the opera.

Comment: @brilliant Sounds fine to me.